# How to get an Array of Objects from Firestore in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

In Swift, to retrieve an array from Firestore I use:

```
currentDocument.getDocument { (document, error) in
  if let document = document, document.exists {
    let people = document.data()!["people"]
    print(people!)
  } else {
    print("Document does not exist")
  }
}
```

And I receive data that looks like this

```
(
  {
    name = "Bob";
    age = 24;
  }
)
```

However, if I were to retrieve the name alone, normally I'd do `print(document.data()!["people"][0]["name"])`.

But the response I get is `Value of type 'Any' has no subscripts`

How do I access the name key inside that object inside the `people` array?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The value returned by `document.data()!["people"]` is of type `Any` and you can't access `[0]` on `Any`.

You'll first need to cast the result to an array, and then get the first item. While I'm not a Swift expert, it should be something like this:

```
let people = document.data()!["people"]! as [Any]
print(people[0])
```

Comment: This crashed the app and gave me this error `Could not cast value of type '__NSArrayM' to 'NSDictionary'` do you know how to solve it?

Comment: Yeah, I think I accidentally made it a dictionary. I updated my answer, but I'd definitely also recommend searching for these error messages (as that's pretty much what I'm doing).

Comment: This worked! Thank you. And I do look up these error messages but sometimes don't understand them. For example, your solution gives me the `people[0]` result. But when I try to get `people[0]["name"]` it tells me `Cannot subscript a value of type '[Any]' with an index of type 'String'`

Comment: So I try to turn `[Any]` into `[Any : String]` but I get `Type 'Any' does not conform to protocol 'Hashable'`... This is how I get stuck...

Comment: `people[0]` is a dictionary, where each key is  string and the value is any type (since it can be both a string and a number). So `people[0] as [String: Any]` is the correct conversion there.

Answer (score 4):

A better way of writing @Frank van Puffelen's answer would be:

```
currentDocument.getDocument { document, error in
  guard error == nil, let document = document, document.exists, let people = document.get("people") as? [Any] else { return }
    print(people)
  }
}
```

The second line may be a little long, but it guards against every error possible.