# How to get an array from Firestore document on Swift 5?

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

Please help me understand the logic reading data from the Firestore document, if one of the values is an **array**. I tried other answers here and sources but never came to a simple working way and understand clearly. Firestore document structure — [example.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PZ5is.png) And Swift class targets for saving (conditional):

```
struct MyStruct {
  var name: String
  var pages: Int
}


let part1 = [MyStruct]()
let name1 = ""
let pages1 = 0
 
let part2 = [MyStruct]()
let name2 = ""
let pages2 = 0

 
func readFirestore() { }
```

What should the document reader function look like to add data to existing targets in the class? Thanks in advance for any help in improving my understanding!

Comment: Read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55368369/how-to-get-an-array-of-objects-from-firestore-in-swift and also this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50233281/how-to-get-an-array-from-firestore

Comment: These were the first answers I checked. What works I posted below as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They helped to deal with familiar, thank you for what they are. As expected, everything is simple. But for the beginner there is nothing more difficult than simplicity

```
func readFirestore() {
    
    self.db.collection("example").document("book").getDocument { (document, error) in

        if error == nil {
            if document != nil && document!.exists {

                //get all document data
                guard let documentData = document!.data() else {return} 

                //get value-array for key "part1"
                let element = documentData["part1"] as? [Any] //print -> Optional([name1, 100])
                
                //get first element in array
                guard let nameDB = element?[0] as? String else {return} //print -> name1
                guard let pagesDB = element?[1] as? String else {return} //print -> 100

                //append in class
                part1.append(MyStruct(name: nameDB, pages: pagesDB))
                name1 = nameDB
                pages1 = pagesDB

            }
        }
    }
}
```